# How to check if first list appear in the same order somewhere in the second list

Tags: python, list

Write a function called sublist. The function takes 2 lists as parameters, and returns True if the items in the first list appear in the same order somewhere in the second list (and False if they don't)

Here are some examples:

```
>>> sublist([2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) True
>>> sublist([1, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) False
>>> sublist([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4]) True
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
def sublist(list1,list2):
    for i in range(len(list2)):
        if list2[i] != list1[i]:
            return False
        return True
```

output:

```
>>> sublist([2,3],[1,2,3,4,5])
False
>>> sublist([1,3],[1,2,3,4,5])
True
>>> sublist([1,2,3],[1,2,1,2,3,4])
True
```

I know that's not entirely right and I know I'm going to have to use [  :  ] to extract a portion of a string or a list but I have no idea where to start. Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: What does your existing code do?

Comment: @SLawson I just added an output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def sublist(list1, list2):
    n = len(list1)
    return any((list1 == list2[i:i + n]) for i in range(len(list2) - n + 1))

print sublist([2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print sublist([1, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print sublist([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

We need to know the length of the sublist, that's what n is for.

Then the [any()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) will stop after the first match in the iterable.  The part inside the any() is a [generator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression), we're comparing the sublist (list1) with each of the sublists in list2, starting from the beginning up to the end.

`i` will range from 0 up to the length of the second list, but you subtract out the length of the first list and then add 1, so you don't go over the end of the index.

Comment: Thank you, that works but if you can, may you please explain to me what is happening?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that made things very clear!